# How to reload properties file in java

Tags: java

Anyone please help me on reloading properties file.
I have code like this

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream trackerFileStream = 
    LoadProperty.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties");
prop.load(trackerFileStream);
```

After loading the properties file through class loader, I modify the properties file.
I am not able to get the latest modifications in the same program execution.

Can anyone please suggest me how to reload the properties file without re-executing the program?

Comment: do you execute the above code, after you altered the properties file?

Comment: Why using properties for something they're not intended for ?

If you need some data modified why not using something like pub/sub topic where the modifier publishes the change for any subscriber to the changes. You can also use events.

Comment: Why do you want to change properties in the classpath and not in a relative(or absolute) location at runtime?

Comment: Just create a new `InputStream`, clear the `prop` Object an `load` it again.

Comment: Are you overwriting the file, once you reload the properties? If you never re-save them to disk, you'll always get the previous result

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be updated you need to check the resource from tome to time and reload the properties.

It is a problem that you are loading properties from classpath. If you use file system you can check the last modified attribute of file and decide whether to reload it. In java 7 you evern can register listener that will call you back when file is modified. You can't do this when loading resource.

But you can do better. Use [configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) package from apache. It already implements reloading logic, so you just can work against "configuration" actually mapped to resource and be sure you always get updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you close/flush your streams correctly? Why using classloader to access the file? If the file is an external file you should access it via normal `FileInputStream` for example

Comment: But in my case i can not specify the exact location of the file. That is why i use class loader

Comment: In production practically your application is packed as a .jar file and it is not possible to modify it runtime. Files need to be both read and modified runtime should be placed to designated absolute or relative paths.

Comment: Thanks jabal, yes after closing the InputStream it is working file(i.e. Am able to read latest value of properties file).