# Change values of property placeholders dynamically

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using fuse6.3 and trying to make the change of following property value dynamically:

```
 <camelContext autoStartup="true" id="_camelContext_app1"
        <propertyPlaceholder
            id="properties"
            location="test.properties,test2.properties"
        />
...
<log id="_log_test_properties" message="===properties:{{remote.host}}"/>
```

In test.properties, if value of remote.host is changed, how to make camel recognize the change?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Lan

Comment: Migrate your property placeholder definition to OSGI blueprint as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983965/how-to-reload-a-properties-file-in-apache-camel-2-12

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am using EAP or spring boot as fuse underlying platform, OSGI is not the choice at this time, many thanks!